# next.js - dynamic route consisting of multiple slugs?

Tags: next.js, dynamic-routing

Is it possible to structure a route that contains dynamic parts in predefined format, such as `/[name]-id[id]`, for example to have routes `/bob-id303` or `/mary-id205`?

What I tried is create a file *[name]-id[id].js*. Inside `getInitialProps` I console.log the `ctx` and it contains

```
  pathname: '/[name]-id[id]',
  query: { 'name]-id[id': 'bob-id303' },
  asPath: '/bob-id303',
```

On the other hand, calling the file *[[name]]-id[id]].js* gives

```
Failed to reload dynamic routes: Error: Optional route parameters are not yet supported ("[[name]-id[id]]").
```

I'd like to get the `name` and `id` directly, then pass them through initial props to the page. I'm aware I can parse `asPath`, but is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use /[slug] and then do `slug.split("-id")`. However you may be better off doing the id alone followed by a fetch for metadata because the name could change and then that url would potentially 404.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing. :)